# Annotate a scatterplot with a text label representing the counts in the data passed through ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe ("mydata") with Z-scores ("scores") and their corresponding ranks ("rank").

```
The ggplot object I have to plot a scatter plot is:
  ggplot(mydata, aes(, x = rank, y = scores)) +
    geom_point()
```

However, I want to be able to add the total observations for scores above 0 and below zero, similar to the image below.

[image]

I know I could pre-calculate the count and pass that to my ggplot object as an annotation, but I was wondering if there is a way to have ggplot calculate those values and annotate accordingly. I want ggplot to calculate those values because I later want to  add a facet_wrap, and I want to make sure that values are calculated based on the data that is being plotted. I think there may be a way to do this using `stat_summary()` and a custom function, but my attempts so far have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option to achieve your desired result using `stat_summary` and a custom function to be passed to the `fun.data` argument. Besides computing the desired stats the function also adds some additional columns including the labels, the vertical alignment and the y label position. Additionally, besides using `after_stat` note the use of `stage` which allows to map a variable on `y` which could then be modified after the stat has been applied.

Using some fake example data based on `iris`:

```r
# Make example data
mydata <- iris
mydata <- mydata |>
  transform(
    scores = (Sepal.Length - mean(Sepal.Length)) / sd(Sepal.Length)
  ) |>
  transform(
    rank = rank(scores)
  )

library(ggplot2)

my_sum <- function(x, y_pos = 2, nudge = .05) {
  y <- c(sum(x < 0), sum(x >= 0))
  label =  paste0(c("z < 0: ", "z >= 0: "), y)
  vjust = c(1, 0)
  data.frame(
    y = y,
    vjust = vjust,
    label = label,
    y_pos = y_pos + nudge * c(-1, 1)
  )
}


p <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = rank, y = scores)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "text",
    fun.data = my_sum,
    aes(
      x = 0,
      y = stage(scores, after_stat = y_pos),
      vjust = after_stat(vjust),
      label = after_stat(label)
    ),
    hjust = 0
  )

p
```

[image]

```r
p +
  facet_wrap(~Species)
```

[image]